# Can I Swap Out A MacBook Hard Drive For Windows

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, pc

I recently purchased a used 2014 MacBook with knowing it has no hard drive. However I do not care for Mac OS, the question here is can I effectively run Windows 10 on a MacBook just by installing a Windows SSD?

If so do I need to format anything or is it good to go.

Answer (score 1):

The SSD will need to be formatted / partioned to work with the « bios » on the macbook, after that Bootcamp will be able to allow you to run windows from a separate partition.

I have not done this, but many do have both OSx and windows installed and working on one machine.

Check out Bootcamp : https://support.apple.com/boot-camp.

Edit : macs don’t have « bios »  (only used that term as it is easily understood by those coming from the pc world...) instead there is a bootrom process to get to the desktop from pressing the on button, this link gives a reasonable explanation of that process which checks ram, the self tests and runs the efi to get to the desktop. See http://www.hawkdive.com/2017/09/understanding-mac-boot-process.html?m=1

Comment: "partitioned to work with the bios on the macbook" Mac doens't use bios. The best way to get windows onto a Mac, is to use bootcamp. It will set everything up in a safe manner, which will prevent issues.

Comment: I used "bios" in arrows - quotes so that the OP would understand as he does not seem to be Mac OS native - I was hoping most mac aware people would understand...

Comment: sorry my bad...

Comment: I think his question is asking only windows, not dual booting with osx and windows which is what bootcamp is for.

Comment: @bakalolo I did not say that you “must” have both installed...